# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: indent-number

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```java
public String filter(String message) {
    if (message == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove formatting, transformer fails to handle wrong indentation correctly.
    message = message.replaceAll(">\\s*[\\r\\n]+\\s*", ">");
    message = message.replaceAll("\\s*[\\r\\n]+\\s*", " "); // for wrapped attribute lists

    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(message));
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", INDENT); // for Java 6

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", INDENT.toString()); // Java 1.5
        transformer.transform(xmlInput, new StreamResult(stringWriter));

        String pretty = stringWriter.toString();
        pretty = pretty.replace("\r\n", "\n");
        return pretty;
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        if (e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof SAXParseException) {
            return message;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

but i get exception here:

```
transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", INDENT); // for Java 6
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: indent-number

my java:

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
```

why i get this error?

Answer (score 14):

I fixed that exception by commenting this line:

```
transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", indent);
```

and adding this line:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

The exception is gone even though the indetation that appears in the browser is incorrect.

Comment: This doesnt appear to work anymore with JDK8 and JBoss EAP 7/Wildfly 10 - I get this error now "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: indent-number"

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```java
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

you should write

```java
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

because not all implementations of `TransformerFactory` have this field: `indent-number`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely because Xalan (as packaged in JDK1.6/1.7) support "indent-number", yet others don't and have their own way of specifying the size of indent. So you have to put in the string appropriate for the XSLT provider. Work out which you're using and see its docs

Aren't standards that don't specify such things great?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the predefined constant `OutputKeys.INDENT`, or if you really insist on hardcoding the value, it should be 'indent', not 'indent-number'.

Comment: It is not enough: it will put elements on new lines, but not add tabs…